# How to shatter/fracture mesh

Tags: mesh, cell-fracture

I'm doing a video game-type project and there are explosions and destruction. Until now, I had to create two meshes for the destruction : One that is entire and one that is destroyed/shattered/destroyed. Is there a way to automatically shatter objects in blender. For exemple, if I make a building, I would like to find an addon or a feature that can divide this building into 50 pieces that look like debris and when I make an explosion, the debris would fly, like in real life.

Comment: If you type "blender destroy object" in youtube you'll find a lot of tutorials on this matter